# Google Maps v3 map tiles not showing up correctly in Chrome & IE

Tags: google-maps

Map shows up fine with ff but in Chrome and IE all the tiles of the map load on top of each other.

EDIT: Solved it by re-typing the initialize function again, might have been a spelling mistake even though I couldn't find any. Thanks again.

Comment: Looks like you have something that's removing the positioning of map tiles. I couldn't find it, though. I'd start by removing all code other than maps code. CSS does not appear to be an issue.

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome for me. I get a map.

Comment: I have removed the extra code but the issue is still there.

After clicking in one of the empty categories from the bottom and clicking back to the first category the map shows up fine.

Comment: I'm doing a setTimeout test where I load an empty map after 3 seconds which seems to bring me closer to solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

                });
});
```